# What can we say about $S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}\operatorname{erf}\left(n\right)}$?

Tags: approximation, closed-form, constants, error-function

I'm really curious If we can find a closed form for this infinite sum :

### $$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}\operatorname{erf}\left(n\right)}$$

As $f(x)=\operatorname{erf}(x)\leq 1$ for $0<x$ and $f(x)$ is increasing we have :

$$\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}<S< \frac{\pi^{2}}{6\operatorname{erf}\left(1\right)}$$

So it converges .

Perhaps we can use the Ramanujan's Master Theorem .

Can we say more and find a decent approximation or at best a closed form ?

Thanks everyone !

Comment: @TymaGaidash I'm not aware of that can you show us ?Thanks for your comment .

Comment: The numerical value is near 1.832772255535836508929639087741696581289699400496956418908417883810103435910182860808530811975077139 (compute the $m$ ($14$ here) first terms and add the sum of $\dfrac 1{n^2}$ for the remainder since $\operatorname{erf}(n)\approx 1$ for $n$ large) and I don't know a closed form.